# Web2py A helper inside TR

Tags: html, web2py, helper

Is it possible to have an A helper create a link inside a TR, like this:

```
    table=TABLE(*[TR(A(*students, URL('pupil_details', vars=dict(fname=students[0], sname=students[2], year=students[5])))) for students in students_on_course])
```

This is inside a controller. Ultimately what I would like to have each element separated by a TD so I can format the resulting table nicely.

I want the TR to be a link to another view, ideally by allowing *the whole TR* to be a link. But when I try the above I get a syntax error saying: Only named arguments may follow *expression

Can you have a TABLE helper generate a TR containing a link?

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A(*students, URL(...))
```

Above you follow `*students` with an additional positional argument, which is not allowed in Python (a `*expression` must come after any other positional arguments).

In any case, you do not specify the "href" of an anchor tag via a positional argument but instead must use the `_href` keyword argument:

```
A(*students, _href=URL(...))
```

You may also need to re-think using `*students`. From your `URL()` code, it looks like `students` is a list or tuple of attributes associated with a single student. Your code is equivalent to:

```
A(student[0], student[1], student[2], ...)
```

which will simply concatenate all the elements of the `students` list, such as:

```
<a href="/yourapp/pupil_details/...">FirstnameSurnameYear</a>
```

Instead, you may want to use the list elements to create a formatted string with some separators (even as simple as `' '.join(students)`).

Comment: I see, is that why my *students doesn't generate a nicely formatted table? Because list elements get concatenated? I thought the TR helper would split the list elements into TDs for me. I've been wondering why it doesn't seem to make a nicely formatted table. Presumably to make that happen I definitely have to use the TD helper? Thanks @Anthony

Comment: If you passed a list to `TR`, it would wrap each element in a `TD`, but `A(*students, ...)` does not produce a list of anchor elements -- it produces a single anchor element. Also, it is not quite clear what you want to generate -- looks like you want each item in the `students` list in a separate table cell, yet the URL that is generated for each cell appears to include multiple items from the list. Feel free to update the question to detail what you're really looking for.

Comment: Duly updated, good advice, thanks. I hoped that putting the A inside a TR I might separate the elements, and then apply the A to all of them. Thanks again.